# Flutter: Setting errorBorder and focusedErrorBorder on TextFormField don't change the border color on input error

Tags: flutter

I have the following `TextFormField` in Flutter:

```
TextFormField(
  keyboardType: this.keyboardInputType,
  inputFormatters: this.inputFormatters,
  focusNode: _textFieldFocus,
  onChanged: onChange,
  validator: validate,
  obscureText: this.isPasswordHidden,
  enableSuggestions: !isPassword,
  autocorrect: !isPassword,
  style: colorlessTextStyle.copyWith(
    color: themeData.color_inputText,
  ),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    filled: true,
    fillColor: _fillColor,
    suffixIcon: this.getSuffixIcon(themeData),
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 20),
    // BORDERS STYLE
    border: this.getBorder(themeData, false),
    focusedBorder: this.getBorder(themeData, false),
    enabledBorder: this.getBorder(themeData, false),
    errorBorder: this.getBorder(themeData, true),
    focusedErrorBorder: this.getBorder(themeData, true),
  ),
)
```

And here is the `getBorder` function (i've checked it and it returns the correct stuff, but still):

```
OutlineInputBorder getBorder(ThemeData themeData, bool error) {
    return OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: error ? AppTheme.RED_500 : themeData.color_inputBorder,
        width: 1,
        style: BorderStyle.solid,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
    );
  }
```

The validator does work and everything else changes color, but the border doesn't change at all.

What might be blocking or overwrite the errorBorder?

Answer (score 0):

I edited some minor things in your codes to create the [minimal working sample](https://dartpad.dev/?id=a186f83c3b6f62a464f994fc707a4988)

First, I defined a form key:

`final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();`

And then enclosed the TextFormField with a Form widget which takes the form key:

```
      Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: TextFormField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          //   inputFormatters: this.inputFormatters,
          //   focusNode: _textFieldFocus,
          onChanged: (onChange) {},
          validator: (f) {
            if (f!.trim().isEmpty) {
              return "Error! Color change";
            }
          },
          obscureText: false,
          enableSuggestions: true,
          autocorrect: true,
          style: const TextStyle(),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            filled: true,
            fillColor: Colors.white24,
            suffixIcon: const Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye_rounded),
            contentPadding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 20),
            // BORDERS STYLE
            border: this.getBorder(Colors.black, false),
            focusedBorder: this.getBorder(Colors.black, false),
            enabledBorder: this.getBorder(Colors.black, false),
            errorBorder: this.getBorder(Colors.black, true),
            focusedErrorBorder: this.getBorder(Colors.black, true),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

I modified getBorder() to look like this (negligible change because I was working in Dartpad)

```
  OutlineInputBorder getBorder(Color themeData, bool error) {
    return OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: error ? Colors.red : Colors.amber,
        width: 1,
        style: BorderStyle.solid,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
    );
  }
```

And then I validated with this button onPress

```
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _formKey.currentState?.validate();
        },
        child: Text('Validate'),
      ),
```

And this is the result below:
[image: Validated Error Textfield]

I hope this gives you a hint of what may be wrong since it should work as it is.. Otherwise I'd need more code to help further. Let me know if it works.